# Scrollspy not working after URL path changes in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

In the web application I am currently working on I have Bootstrap's Scrollspy as well as a scroll to top button. Both work fine initially but after navigating to another page of my application and navigating back the scroll is totally disabled. Can't figure out what is causing it.

You can check it out at emeraldreview.herokuapp.com or check my repo at https://github.com/jamesemcc/review-site-template

I'm not sure what code exactly I would include for you to look over so I figure this is easiest. Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a turbolinks issue. In `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, replace

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
});
```

with

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // your code
});
```

Turbolinks works by simply switching out the content of the body tag every time a link is clicked on your site. The switching of content doesn't trigger jQuery's `$(document).ready()` handler, but using the `turbolinks:load` event should do the trick.

I hope that helps solve the issue, and good luck!

Comment: @jamesemcc no problem, glad I could help!

Comment: hey, I'm not sure if you could help me with another scroll issue. But for my mobile menu, after I click on a link to the about or contact section the scroll does not function properly either.